# phonegap window.requestFileSystem args

Tags: cordova, filesystems

What's the purpose of the second argument of this funcion? It's always set to zero, but I've never found out what it's used for.

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, success, fail);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This text is from cordova.js:
@param size  indicates how much storage space, in bytes, the application expects to need

It seems that requestFileSystem will fail if the availability of the disk is smaller than size param.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax :
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onSuccess, onError);

Description :

Here first parameter can be LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT/LocalFileSystem.TEMPORARY, second parameter determines Storage Space, third parameter determines success on file access and fourth parameter determines error while file handling.